# How to fix 302 redirect and make it 301?

Tags: php, symfony1, seo, symfony-1.4

I have a website built using PHP Symfony Framework. The site is built using 4 languages, so we have built sub domains of it like

```
en.xyz.com
es.xyz.com
de.xyz.com
it.xyz.com
```

Following is the code snippet I have used for setting user culture from domain name
http://snippets.symfony-project.org/snippet/332

Now the problem is, we are doing some SEO on the website and it is returning 302 redirect error for all these 3 URLs.

I want to fix this and make these URLs 301 as this is what our SEO is suggesting.

Any idea how to do that ?

Comment: Which Symfony version are you using? (You should not tag your question "symfony1" if you're using Symfony 2, and you should not tag your question "symfony2" if you are using Symfony 1.)

Comment: It is symfony 1. Does it help now?

Comment: Provide us the redirect code/definition

Comment: Please put your (relevant) code directly into your question.  Linking to external sites doesn't guarantee that the code will always be available in the future

Comment: The code is given on the URL, did u check it ?

Comment: But this snippet doesn't provide any `redirect` so we can't help you with just this code. Where does the redirect occurs?

Answer (score 3):

The redirect method takes 2 parameters.

```
$this->redirect($url, 301)
```

This should work for you.

Comment: No, the method takes 3 parameters. The status code is the 3rd one. The 2nd is a delay in seconds.